# Alternating + and - in a sum

Tags: shell, alternating

I'm looking for a way to alternate + and - in a whole string of numbers seperated by plusses atm.
I need it to be Number1 - Number2 + Number3 - Number4 etc.
It has to be a command line command (hope that made sense o_0) and I need to be able to pipe the HUGE sum into it. So best of all would be a sed command. Thank you!

My command line as this far :

```
cat oneven.txt | sed 's/\(\w\)/4\/\1/g' | bc -l | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\1 +/g' |sed 's/\(\w.*\w\)+\(\w.*\w\)/\1-\2/g'| tr "\n" " " | cut -c -11998
```

Oneven ==> uneven (it contains all the numbers till 1000 that are (you guessed it) uneven.

Tried: a sed command that would take a pair of numbers and change the + between them into a min. No result. no minuses were added
Example (Before the alternating):

> 4.00000000000000000000 + 1.33333333333333333333 + .80000000000000000000 + .57142857142857142857 + .44444444444444444444 + .28571428571428571428 + .09523809523809523809 + .05714285714285714285 + .04081632653061224489 + .03174603174603174603 + .16666666666666666666 + .05555555555555555555 + .03333333333333333333 + .02380952380952380952 + .01851851851851851851 + .11764705882352941176 + .03921568627450980392 + .02352941176470588235 + .01680672268907563025 + .01307189542483660130 + .09090909090909090909 + .03030303030303030303 + .01818181818181818181 + .01298701298701298701 + .01010101010101010101 + .07407407407407407407 + .02469135802469135802 + .01481481481481481481 + .01058201058201058201 + .00823045267489711934 + .06250000000000000000 + .02083333333333333333 + .01250000000000000000 + [...]

I need it to be Number1 - Number2 + Number3 - Number4 etc.
It has to be a command line command (hope that made sense o_0) and I need to be able to pipe the HUGE sum into it.

Comment: You need to show what you've tried so far

Comment: It may be helpful to include some code of where you are stuck.

Comment: Check out: [Replace every Nth occurrence](http://backreference.org/2012/08/22/replace-every-nth-occurrence). Now figure out how to apply in your case. :P

Comment: @HarshGupta. I don't think i'm allowed to use awk or perl. I'm a university student, trying to make his exercises and we have not (yet) talked about awk or perl. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Is the sum split over several lines as you show above or is it all on the same line? Any constraints on it such as line length or number of numbers on the same line?

Comment: "I'm looking for:" is not a good title.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, as far as i'm aware all is one line (it just looks like multiple) No constraints as far as line length

Comment: @crashmstr Wanted to tickle the crowd's curiosity, edited now :D

Comment: I think the answer is 3.1415926 :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell, indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is on one line, then you don't need the `tr` command there. If it isn't, then the `tr` should precede the `sed`, as `sed` processes each line separately, and the solution wouldn't work if the pairs of numbers are on different lines.

As for the solution itself, your idea to take pairs of numbers with a plus between them is good, but you didn't specify a good enough regex for this, so it didn't work. Here is mine:

```
sed -e 's/\([^-+]\+\)+\([^-+]\+\)/\1-\2/g'
```

This says:

- A non-empty string of characters which are neither `+` nor `-`
- followed by a `+`
- followed by another such string.

Your regex (`\(\w.*\w\)+\(\w.*\w\)`) is wrong because it actually means:

- A word character
- Zero or more unconstrained characters
- Another word character
- `+`
- A word character
- Zero or more unconstrained characters
- Another word character

Why is it wrong? Because your plus is not actually surrounded by word characters, but by spaces. So this doesn't actually match anything on the line.

Even if you take spaces into consideration, this would still not match your actual numbers, because some of them begin with a decimal point, which is not a word character.

And even if you fixed that, the `.*` would also match plus signs, meaning that if it's greedy, it may only replace the last plus.